# Managing dplyr group_by function to keep the grouping variable when used in combination with group_modify

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to use the function `group_modify` (which I've learned about [here](https://youtu.be/IqFUNM-1m78?t=120)).

The goal is to take a `data.frame`, split it with `group_by` and then apply a home made function that do some reorganisation (namely sorting, selecting the "best row" and if more than one, average the values).  I need the output `data.frame` to have **all** the columns of the original one.

Here is a RE that will make everything clearer:

The data:

```
library(dplyr)
(dd <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"), cat = c("s2", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s2", "s2"), val = 1:7))
  id cat val
1  a  s2   1
2  a  s1   2
3  b  s1   3
4  b  s1   4
5  c  s3   5
6  c  s2   6
7  c  s2   7
```

My function (basic one that shows my problem, but not exactly the one I'm actually using):

```
simple_fun <- function(slice, key){
  big_out_to_show_error <<- slice

  temp1 <- arrange(slice, cat)
  
  temp2 <- temp1 %>% 
    filter(cat==temp1$cat[1])

  if(nrow(temp2)>1) {
    temp2 <- temp2 %>% 
      group_by(id, cat) %>% 
      summarise(val = mean(val))
  }
  
  return(data.frame(temp2))
  
}
```

The output I want (one row per ID having the "best" `cat` and if more than one row, average of `val` and having **all** the variables from the original `data.frame`):

```
  id cat val
a  a  s1 2.0
b  b  s1 3.5
c  c  s2 6.5
```

My try with `dplyr::group_modify` function throws an error:

```
dd %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   group_modify(simple_fun)
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error: Column `id` is unknown
```

This is because the `slice` that is used do not include the grouping variable.  This can be seen by this simple code that uses the line `big_out_to_show_error <<- slice` in the main function and limiting to `id=="a"`:

```
filter(dd, id=="a") %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   group_modify(simple_fun)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   id [1]
  id    cat     val
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 a     s1        2

big_out_to_show_error
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  cat     val
  <fct> <int>
1 s2        1
2 s1        2
```

How can I manage the `group_by` function to still throw the grouping variable in the slice so my function works with `group_modify`?

As a side note, I'm really trying to understand and fix the `dplyr` `group_by`  behavior.  I already know the base R way to do it:

```
split(dd, dd$id) %>% 
  lapply(simple_fun) %>% 
  do.call("rbind", .)
  id cat val
a  a  s1 2.0
b  b  s1 3.5
c  c  s2 6.5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_modify()` creates two objects for each group - a tibble containing the subset data, and a separate single row tibble containing the group information.

Because the group information will be restored automatically when `group_modify()` returns the data, it's generally not necessary for this information to be kept in the subset data so, by default, it is removed.  However, you can use the `.keep` argument to retain it but this will cause an error if the group variables are present when the data is returned by your function.

So you can fix your function by using the `.keep` argument and then removing the grouping variables before the data is returned:

```
simple_fun <- function(slice, key){

  temp1 <- arrange(slice, cat)
  
  temp2 <- temp1 %>% 
    filter(cat==temp1$cat[1])
  
  if(nrow(temp2)>1) {
    temp2 <- temp2 %>% 
      group_by(id, cat) %>% 
      summarise(val = mean(val), .groups = "drop")
  }   
  temp2 %>%
    select(-id)      
}

dd %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_modify(simple_fun, .keep = TRUE)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
  id    cat     val
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 a     s1      2  
2 b     s1      3.5
3 c     s2      6.5
```

You can also simplify the function to sidestep this issue altogether:

```
simple_fun2 <- function(slice, key){

slice %>% 
    slice_min(cat, 1) %>%
    summarise(cat = unique(cat),
              val = mean(val))
}

dd %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_modify(simple_fun2)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
  id    cat     val
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 a     s1      2  
2 b     s1      3.5
3 c     s2      6.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really informative.  I wasn't aware of the `slice_min` function, there is really one tidyverse function for everything...  My actual code as to run on 1.3 millions lines and it was quite slow, so I tested the different options and showed that the `slice_min` approach is the fastest, when used with a `lapply` (you can look at the benchmark I just produce in another answer).

Answer (score 0):

27 ϕ 9 answer is perfect and answer my question.  Now, considering that there are multiple options to analyse the dataset and that my dataset is quite big (1.3 million lines), I did a quick benchmark to compare the Base R (`split`/`lapply`) and the Tidyverse (`group_by`/`group_modify`) approaches using both possible functions (the one that uses `arrange` and the one that uses `slice_min`).

It may not be optimal/perfect/state of the art programmation but it was a quick and dirty comparison which give a fair idea of the most efficient way to do this analysis.

```
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

nbrows <- 200
set.seed(1234)
bigdd <- data.frame(id = sample(nbrows/2, nbrows, replace = T), 
                    cat = sample(c("S1", "S2", "S3"), nbrows, replace = T),
                    val = runif(nbrows)) %>% 
  arrange(id)

f_baser_arrange <- function(dd){
  
  simple_fun0 <- function(slice, key){
    temp1 <- arrange(slice, cat)
    temp2 <- temp1 %>% 
      filter(cat==temp1$cat[1])
    if(nrow(temp2)>1) {
      temp2 <- temp2 %>% 
        group_by(id, cat) %>% 
        summarise(val = mean(val), .groups = 'drop')
    }
    return(data.frame(temp2))
  }
  
  split(dd, dd$id) %>% 
    lapply(simple_fun0) %>% 
    do.call("rbind", .)
}

f_baser_slice_min <- function(dd){
  simple_fun3 <- function(slice, key){
    slice %>% 
      slice_min(cat, 1) %>%
      summarise(id = unique(id),
                cat = unique(cat),
                val = mean(val))
  }
  
  split(dd, dd$id) %>% 
    lapply(simple_fun3) %>% 
    do.call("rbind", .)
}

f_tidy_arrange <- function(dd){
  simple_fun1 <- function(slice, key){
    temp1 <- arrange(slice, cat)
    temp2 <- temp1 %>% 
      filter(cat==temp1$cat[1])
    if(nrow(temp2)>1) {
      temp2 <- temp2 %>% 
        group_by(cat) %>% 
        summarise(val = mean(val), .groups = 'drop')
    }
    return(data.frame(temp2))
  }
  
  dd %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    group_modify(simple_fun1)
}

f_tidy_slice_min <- function(dd){
  simple_fun2 <- function(slice, key){
    slice %>% 
      slice_min(cat, 1) %>%
      summarise(cat = unique(cat),
                val = mean(val))
  }
  
  dd %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    group_modify(simple_fun2)
}

res <- microbenchmark(f_baser_arrange(bigdd),
               f_baser_slice_min(bigdd),
               f_tidy_arrange(bigdd),
               f_tidy_slice_min(bigdd),
               times = 100)

data.frame(res) %>% 
  mutate(Philosophy = ifelse(grepl("baser", expr), "Base R", "Tidyverse"),
         Method = ifelse(grepl("arrange", expr), "arrange", "slice_min")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Philosophy, y=time, color=Method))+
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.5))
```

Which produces:
[image]

We notice that the base R `split`/`lapply` approach is generally faster than the Tidyverse `group_by`/`group_modify` way.  We also notice that @27 ϕ 9 `slice_min` is faster than my original `arrange` approach.

Also, the base R approach and be speed up even more by changing the `lapply` with `parLapply`.